# Return model with custom query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have defined custom query inside my eloquent model and I'm wondering what is the best way to include its result when I get the model.

I know that there is the protected $with, but that accepts only relationships then there is $appends but that is for attributes and my query returns whole object and I don't know if it's good idea to include it as attribute.

Also, if there is way to do this inside a models method, I would like to hear about it, because I don't necessarily need to have this information on every model instance.

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

**Edit:**
I am familiar with $with and relations.
What I'm asking is how do I get something like this to eager load:

```
public function thisIsMyQuery()
{
    return DB::table('example')->where('const', '>', 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your need, you only want to eager load a relation. To do so, you have to define a relation inside your model, and add the name of the method, inside the `$with` array.

example :

```
// Inside your model class

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['comments'];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}

// Usage

$post = Post::find(1)
$post->comments; // here are the related comments
```

Comment: No, I want to eager load custom DB query that I have created. So it is not a relation and since it's not a relation I can't use the $with.

Comment: why would you like to eager load an custom query instead of running it after ?

Comment: Well, what's the difference isn't relation just a blueprint for a query. All I am asking is if it is possible to do. If the query can return the same data as relation why shouldn't it be able to eager load is my question? If I am not mistaken it is better to eager load than having a lot of queries on page.

Comment: Eager loading à relation is like making joint un pure SQL. You're aggregating data in the same query. But it's not possible to join two tables without data in common. The same goes for eager loading relations.

Comment: One other thing, one big request isn't always faster than two medium ones. In most cases as long as you dont request your database inside loop you dont need to worry that much. Having less complex requests allows you to have more maintenable and readdable code and make profit of the database cache system